# Assembly Conditional Jump

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements

I just started with assembly and it's going great, but there's 1 thing that I just don't understand.
How do conditional jumps work?

I have a sample of assembly code here.

```
TEST EAX, EAX
FCLEX
JGE SHORT 004022B1
```

I see that when a certain condition is greater or equal, a jump will be made to 004022B1.

But what is that condition and where is it checked?

I assume the condition must be TEST EAX,EAX. But I'm not sure what it does.

Can anyone explain to me how conditional jumps work and where the condition is checked/stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conditional jumps (and some other instructions) use flags. These flags are bits in the (E/R)[FLAGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register_%28computing%29) register. `test a, b` sets the flags according to the result of `and a, b`, without updating `a` with the result. `fclex` does not change any normal flags (it changes FPU flags of course).

`jge` tests* whether the value of the sign flag is equal to the overflow flag. `test a, b` sets the overflow flag to zero and the sign flag to the signbit of the result of `and a, b`. So the jump will be taken if `eax` is positive.

*: note that it does not test for "greater or equal". That interpretation is valid when the flags are checked after a `cmp` (and some other instructions). It really just looks at the flags.

Comment: So if a is, for instance, 1 and b is 2 the signbit of the result will be 0. And if a is -1 and b is -2 the signbit will be 1 because it is a negative number.
Is this correct?